# RMI call with Remote interface at ejb 3 in weblogic

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, rmi

I have some problem with this code , when i am trying to call the Remote interface , that is deploy in other server (prewlsapp2) .
this is my client :

```
Hashtable<String, String> pro = new Hashtable<String, String>();  
              //Properties pro = new Properties();  
              pro.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");  
               pro.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://prewlsapp2:7661");  
               //pro.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "hemanth");  
              //pro.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "hemnathn1"); 


               Context ctx = new InitialContext(pro);  
               MessagesEntityFacadeRemote t = (MessagesEntityFacadeRemote)ctx.lookup("MessagesEntityFacade#Message.MessagesEntityFacadeRemote");
               GOSIDebug.debugMessages("MessagesEntityFacadeRemote  "+t);
              List tt = t.findByTargetID("2004");

               System.out.print("xyz");
```

The   System.out.print("xyz"); never printed after call t.findByTargetID("2004") , also there is no Exception printed !

My Remote interface is :

```
    package Message;

import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface MessagesEntityFacadeRemote {

    void create(MessagesEntity messagesEntity); 

    void edit(MessagesEntity messagesEntity);

    void remove(MessagesEntity messagesEntity);

    MessagesEntity find(MessagesEntity id);

    List<MessagesEntity> findAll();

     List<MessagesEntity> findByTargetID(String target) ;

    List<MessagesEntity> findRange(int[] range);

     MessagesEntity findByMessageID(String target);

      List<MessagesEntity> findNextByTargetID(String target,int f,int l) ;

    int count();

}
```

Also my Impl  :

```
package Message;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

@Stateless(mappedName="MessagesEntityFacade")
public class MessagesEntityFacade implements MessagesEntityFacadeLocal, MessagesEntityFacadeRemote, Serializable {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "Messaging_SystemPU")
    private EntityManager em;


    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() { 
        return em;
    }



    @Override
    public MessagesEntity find(MessagesEntity id) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }


    @Override
    public List<MessagesEntity> findAll() {

    return em.createQuery("select object(o) from MessagesEntity as o").getResultList();

    }



    @Override
        public List<MessagesEntity> findByTargetID(String target) throws Exception  {


        System.out.println("target are"+target);
        Query result=null;
        try{
       ArrayList <MessagesEntity>listOFMessages=new ArrayList<MessagesEntity>();
       List results = new ArrayList();
       MessagesEntity[] users;
       System.out.print("hiiiiiiiiiii");
            result = em.createNativeQuery("select * from T_MESSAGES  p where p.target = ?1 order by p.creationtimestamp desc",Message.MessagesEntity.class);
        System.out.print("out hiiiiiiii");
        result.setParameter(1, target);


        // results = result.getResultList();

      //  System.out.print("beforrrrrr");
            // users = (MessagesEntity[])result.getResultList().toArray(new MessagesEntity[0]);
       //  System.out.println("usersusers"+users);



        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.print("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs"); 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         return result.getResultList();

    //SELECT c from PolicyShiftEntityEJB c where c.policyId = :policyId
      /*Query query=em.createQuery("SELECT object(c) FROM MessagesEntity as c WHERE  c.target = :target order by c.messageid desc");
      query.setParameter("target", target);
      List res= query.getResultList();

      System.out.print("ressssssss"+res);
        listOFMessages.addAll(res);

        return listOFMessages;*/
     // return query.getResultList();

    }

    @Override
    public MessagesEntity findByMessageID(String messageId) {

        Query result = em.createNativeQuery("select * from T_MESSAGES  p where p.messageid = ?1 ",Message.MessagesEntity.class);
        result.setParameter(1, messageId);
        return (MessagesEntity) result.getSingleResult();

    }

    @Override
    public List<MessagesEntity> findNextByTargetID(String target,int f,int l) {

        Query result = em.createNativeQuery("select * from T_MESSAGES  p where p.target = ?1 order by p.creationtimestamp desc",Message.MessagesEntity.class);
         result.setParameter(1, target);
         result.setFirstResult((f - 1) * l);
         result.setMaxResults(l);
         return result.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public void create(MessagesEntity messagesEntity) {
       em.persist(messagesEntity);
    }

    @Override
    public void edit(MessagesEntity messagesEntity) {
        em.merge(  messagesEntity);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(MessagesEntity messagesEntity) {
     em.remove(em.merge(messagesEntity));
    }

    @Override
    public List<MessagesEntity> findRange(int[] range) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public int count() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }


}
```

Hint : when I am trying to call this function in my clients (`count()`), the Exception was :

```
 java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at $Proxy334.count(Unknown Source)
    at gosi.core.security.viewcontrollers.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:1062)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:502)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:251)
    at gosi.core.security.viewcontrollers.SIMISLoginProxyServlet.doPost(SIMISLoginProxyServlet.java:124)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3495)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2180)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2086)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1406)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Message.MessagesEntityFacade_lpk28i_MessagesEntityFacadeRemoteImpl_1030_WLStub.count()
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1605)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.getTargetMethod(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:162)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.invoke(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:53)
    ... 25 more
```

But when I call this function `findByTargetID(String target)` , nothing printed ! and I don't know if there is some Exception or not , olso this line in my client never printed   `System.out.print("xyz");` , thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which version of WebLogic you're using, but in 10.3 we used to have similar issues with executing EJBs via remote calls and having the generics in the Remote interface was what was causing the issue. Try removing the generic type parameters from the interface and see if that works for you.

i.e.

```
List<MessagesEntity> findByTargetID(String target) ;
```

becomes

```
List findByTargetID(String target) ;
```

Comment: thank you so much , i made the change , now the error is `:Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Message.MessagesEntityFacade_lpk28i_MessagesEntityFacadeRemoteImpl_1030_WLStub.findByTargetID(java.lang.String)`

Comment: You should be ok to have the local interface and implementation with the generics, and not have the generics in the remote interface, as far as I remember. You may have to clear down the compiled EJB classes from the WebLogic directory (exact location escapes me now, but I think the directory is called EJBCompiler or similar). WebLogic doesn't always detect that the EJB has changed and force a recompile. If this does solve your problems, can you please accept the answer? Cheers

Comment: thank you for your help , the problem about the generics , there is a bug in weblogic , so you can't make the remote inteface generics .